# Не могу заставить работать SQL запрос

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Нужно вывести пользователей для акции то есть сегодняшний день должен быть в промежутке 3 дня до и 3 дня после их дня рождения , то-есть временной промежуток в 7 дней.**

БД большая(больше 100.000 строк, даты есть только в 28.000) и немного косячная, в столбе с датами есть не только даты но и NULL и просто поля со вбитым в них пробелом. Мне сказали заставить запрос всё это обходить.

БД выглядит примерно так

```
CREATE TABLE Partners (
    ID int,
    Name nvarchar(255),
    MOL nvarchar(255),
    Adress nvarchar(255),
    DateOfBirth nvarchar(255)
   ....
);
```

**Примеры показать не могу, там личная информация.**

За 3 дня у меня получилось примерно вот это:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Partners 
WHERE ISDATE(DateOfBirth) = 1 
  AND GETDATE() BETWEEN DATEADD(day, -4, CONVERT(CHAR(6),DateOfBirth) + CONVERT(CHAR(4), YEAR(GETDATE())))
  AND DATEADD(day, 4, CONVERT(CHAR(6),DateOfBirth) + CONVERT(CHAR(4), YEAR(GETDATE())))
```

Пример: `GETDATE()` : `Feb  2 2021  4:41PM`

Запроса выдает пару строк а потом выдает вот это:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

В результате просто нужна таблица со всеми пользователями подходящими под условие.

Comment: Судя по синтаксису - это SQL Server. Верно? Выложите: CREATE TABLE таблицы, INSERT INTO с примером данных (3-5 записей), тестовое значение GETDATE() и требуемый результат для таких данных.

Comment: Суть проблемы - если в поле DateOfBirth не дата, это никоим образом не значит, что при отрицательном результате проверки не будут проверяться остальные условия отбора. Тут-то и возникает ошибка. Если количество записей невелико - лучше в CTE отобрать записи, где в этом поле дата, а уже в основном запросе проверять всё остальное.

Comment: *Нужно вывести пользователей в промежутке 3 дня до и 3 дня после их дня рождения, то-есть временной промежуток в 7 дней.* Достаточно посчитать разность в годах (`DATEDIFF(YEAR, ..)`) между датой рождения и границами промежутка. Если в течение этих 7 дней был ДР - разности не совпадут.

Comment: Добавил то что вы просили. И у меня возник вопрос про просчёт разности в годах, я не сосем понимаю как

Comment: Гм... а почему поле заведомо с датой - строкового типа-то? Как насчёт привести в порядок, преобразовать его в DATE? а все невалидные значения соответственно причесать под NULL. *у меня возник вопрос про просчёт разности в годах, я не сосем понимаю как* [DATEDIFF (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Используйте TRY_CONVERT вместо CONVERT

Answer (score 0):

Короче говоря запрос заработал, но для этого пришлось исправить много данных(примерно 1000 строк). Работники часто промахиваются по кнопкам или просто торопятся, со временем такого становится много.

Так-же я немного улучшил запрос:

```
SET DATEFORMAT dmy;
SELECT * 
FROM Partners 
WHERE 
    DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR,GETDATE(),DateOfBirth) ,GETDATE()) 
        BETWEEN DATEADD(day, -3, DateOfBirth) AND DATEADD(day, 4, DateOfBirth)
```

В отличии от предыдущей версии может работать с такими форматами дат: "d.mm.yyyy", "dd.m.yyyy", "dd.mm.yy".

Всем кто столкнётся с такой-же проблемой как у меня оставлю то как я искал и исправлял кривые даты.

**Поиск поломанных данных:**

Для дат формата "d.mm.yyyy", "dd.m.yyyy" "dd.mm.yy":

```
WHERE DateOfBirth > '' AND DateOfBirth = CONVERT(CHAR(9),DateOfBirth)
```

Для дат формата "yyyy":

```
WHERE DateOfBirth = CONVERT(CHAR(5),DateOfBirth)
```

Для дат с пробелами:

```
WHERE DateOfBirth LIKE '% %' AND ISDATE(DateOfBirth) = 1
```

Для дат с лишними нулями:

```
WHERE ISDATE(DateOfBirth)= 1 AND LEN(DateOfBirth)>10
```

для любых отклонений от формата 'dd.MM.yyyy':

```
WHERE DateOfBirth <> FORMAT (CONVERT(DATE,DateOfBirth),'dd.MM.yyyy') AND DateOfBirth > ''
```

Для дат с неправильным годом(1/2):

```
WHERE DateOfBirth > '' AND SUBSTRING(DateOfBirth,7,4) > 2021
```

Для дат с неправильным годом(2/2):

```
WHERE DateOfBirth > '' AND SUBSTRING(DateOfBirth,7,4) < 1900
```

Люди родившиеся в високосный год(пишет что 29.02.xxxx слишком большая дата):

```
DateOfBirth > '' AND SUBSTRING(DateOfBirth,1,2) > 28 AND SUBSTRING(DateOfBirth,4,2) = 2
```

**Исправление поломанных данных:**

Для дат формата "yyyy":

```
SET NULL
```

Для дат с ошибками в формате (НА ЛИШНИЕ 0 НЕ РАБОТАЕТ):

```
SET FORMAT (CONVERT(DATE,DateOfBirth),'dd.MM.yyyy')
```

Для дат с неправильным годом

```
SET DateOfBirth = CONVERT(CHAR(6),DateOfBirth) + CONVERT(CHAR(4), YEAR(GETDATE()))
```

Люди родившиеся в високосный год:

```
SET DateOfBirth = FORMAT(CONVERT(DATE,'01.03.' + SUBSTRING(DateOfBirth,7,4)),'dd.MM.yyyy')
```

так же можно:

```
SET DateOfBirth = FORMAT(CONVERT(DATE,'28.02.' + SUBSTRING(DateOfBirth,7,4)),'dd.MM.yyyy')
```

**ПЕРЕД ТЕМ КАК ИЗМЕНЯТЬ ЧТО ЛИБО В БД ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО СОГЛАСУЙТЕ ЭТО, ОСОБЕННО ЕСЛИ СТОИТ НЕПРАВИЛЬНАЯ ДАТА, ЛУЧШЕ ПОЗВОНИТЬ КЛИЕНТУ И СПРОСИТЬ ЕГО ДАТУ РОЖДЕНИЯ.**